# Filtered homotopy colimits of spectra

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy, infinity-categories

Let $\mathcal{I}: \mathbb{N} \to \operatorname{Sp}$ be a diagram in the infinity category of spectra. Let $\pi_0(\mathcal{I})$ denote the corresponding $1$-categorical diagram (i.e. compose $\mathcal{I}$ with the functor $\pi_0$ taking $\operatorname{Sp}$ its homotopy category, and view $\mathbb{N}$ as a $1$-category).

Then I can do two things: (1) take the homotopy colimit of $\mathcal{I}$.  (2) take the $1$-categorical colimit of $\pi_0(\mathcal{I})$.

**Question:** do (1) and (2) produce isomorphic objects in $\pi_0(Sp)$?

Remark: I would hope that these should coincide, because there is a map from the colimit to the hocolimit and I would hope that taking homotopy groups sends filtered colimits in $\operatorname{Sp}$ to colimits in $\operatorname{Ab}$ (but I haven't been able to find a reference, so maybe this is too naive; one potential issue is that colimits might not exist?).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by (3)? A model structure does not live on the homotopy category, instead it lives on some 1-category not naturally determined by the homotopy category (and a priori there is no canonical way to lift a diagram in the homotopy category into some choice of model category)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I was naively assuming such a lift existed. I will remove (3) (at least until I figure out a sensible replacement)

Comment: I think this might follow from Dugger's Theorem (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+homotopy+colimit): Colimits in the (presentable) $\infty$-category of spectra agree with homotopy colimits in the respective combinatorial model category, so by Dugger $\kappa$-filtered colimits in $\operatorname{Sp}$ are 1-categorical colimits. In the case of spectra, I would guess that (as for the Quillen model structure on spaces) one can choose generating cofibrations to start and end at compact objects, so by the proof in the above article we can set $\kappa = \aleph_0$.

Comment: @MarkusZetto I don't see how this is related to the colimit in the homotopy category. My current suspicion is that such colimits might fail to exist. On the other hand, it might be true that any diagram in the homotopy category indexed by $\mathbb{N}$ can be lifted to the model 1-category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a partial answer, not addressing the relation to homotopy colimits in a model category presenting $\mathcal{C}$ (but I think there should be some reasonable statement there, the slogan is certainly that homotopy colimits in a model category present the $\infty$-categorical colimits).

But for colimits in the homotopy category, let us observe the following. Consider the diagram
$$
\mathbb{S} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{S}\xrightarrow{3}\ldots.
$$
in $\mathrm{Sp}$. If this would admit a colimit $X$ in the homotopy category, $X$ would have to satisfy $[X, Y] = \lim [\mathbb{S},Y] = \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\pi_0(Y))$ for any $Y$. If such $X$ existed, mapping into a cofiber sequence $Y_0\to Y_1 \to Y_2$ gives a sequence
$$
[X,Y_0] \to [X,Y_1]\to [X,Y_2]
$$
which is exact in the middle.
But for the sequence $H\mathbb{Q} \to H\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to \Sigma H\mathbb{Z}$, this would mean that the sequence
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \to 0
$$
is exact. But it is not, the middle term is something uncountable.

In $\mathrm{Sp}$, the diagram does of course admit an $\infty$-categorical colimit, namely $H\mathbb{Q}$. But maps out of it are more complicated: they fit into a short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Q},\pi_1(Y))\to [H\mathbb{Q},Y] \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q},\pi_0(Y))\to 0
$$

The general phenomenon is that $\mathbb{N}$-indexed limits and colimits in $\infty$-categories already see some higher information invisible to the homotopy category, the so-called $\lim^1$-terms.

Comment: Regarding your remark: It is still true that homotopy groups commute with filtered colimits, i.e. as functors $\pi_n: \mathrm{Sp}\to \mathrm{Ab}$. This is not related to colimits in the homotopy category though.